# Set axis limits for plot.PCA - strange behaviour (FactoMineR)

Tags: r, plot, pca

I want to plot the result of a PCA with the package factominer. When one plots a PCA it is good practice to resize the graph so that its H/L ratio is in proportion to the %variance explained by each axis.

So I tried first to resize the graph simply by stretching the window: it obviously fails and keep the points in the middle **instead of stretching them too.**

```
library(FactoMineR)
out <- PCA(mtcars)
```

[image]

Then I try to force the `xlim` and `ylim` arguments to be fixed (`?plot.PCA`)

```
plot.PCA(out, choix="ind", xlim=c(-6,6), ylim=c(-4, 4))
```

[image]

Same problem, the xlim limits are not respected...

Can someone explain this behaviour and knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is the result of the call to `plot` inside `plot.PCA`:

```
plot(0, 0, main = titre, xlab = lab.x, ylab = lab.y, 
     xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, col = "white", asp = 1, ...)
```

`plot` is called with parameter `asp` set to `1`, which guarantees that the *y/x* ratio stays the same, so when you try to resize the window, the `xlim` are recomputed.

In `plot.window` you can find the "meaning" of `asp`:

> If asp is a finite positive value then the window is set up so that one data unit in the x direction is equal in length to asp * one data unit in the y direction.

You can try

```
plot(0, 0, main = "", xlab = "", ylab = "", xlim = c(-6, 6), ylim = c(-4, 4), col = "white", asp = 1)
```

and resizing the window, and then the same with

```
plot(0, 0, main = "", xlab = "", ylab = "", xlim = c(-6, 6), ylim = c(-4, 4), col = "white")
```

to see the difference.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand what's happening. So can I remove this option from the PCA plot or not? I tried to set to differnet value but I get an error

Comment: I guess you can act directly on the plot call but you'll have to modify the plot.PCA function

Comment: ok right that's what i suspected. thanks for your help. i'll accept the answer. A+