# How do I change the axis sizes in pca2d?

Tags: r, pca

I'm using the `pca3d` package to plot principle components 1-5 of gene expression data. I was having a hard time standardizing the 3d plot, so instead I plotted PC1 vs PC2, PC2 vs PC3, etc. My code for that is below

```
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
for(n in 1:4){

  pca2d(pcaSix$x[,n:(n+1)], # Mclust Grouping - module Genes
        title = "Six Genes From Abel, et al. 2011",
        shape = 16,
        group = clustersMod1six,
        radius = 1,
        legend = NULL,
        show.centroids = FALSE,
        show.ellipses = TRUE,
        col = ClusterColorsSix,
        axe.titles = c(paste("PCA",
                             n,
                             sep = ""),
                       paste("PCA",
                             n+1,
                             sep = "")
                       ),
        xlim = c(-1,1),
        ylim = c(-1,1)
        ) 

}
```

The issue that I'm having is that the `xlim` and `ylim` arguments do not appear to have any effect on the plot, I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40489711/set-axis-limits-for-plot-pca-strange-behaviour-factominer) that suggested using the `asp` argument, but setting `asp` did not allow me to change the axes.

Does anyone know how I could force `pca2d` to change the axes limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without modifying the function, there is no way to control the axes. See [line 32](https://github.com/cran/pca3d/blob/master/R/pca2d.R#L32):

```
plot(NULL, type= "n", 
  xlim= prange$x,
  ylim= prange$y,
  xlab= xlab,
  ylab= ylab,
  bty= "none"
  )
```